# CSS text rotate3d over video - shows part of the text behind video

Tags: css, safari, html5-video

I need to show CSS font animation over a HTML5 video. It works fine for many animations, but animation using rotate3d function behaves strange only in Safari browser.

In any other browser the video looks like,
[image]

But in Safari it looks like,
[image]

I have created a plunk for this,
http://plnkr.co/edit/R2nM2nzjOXIC2bipflER?p=preview

Css is,

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
      from {
        transform: perspective(600px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      }

      to {
        transform: perspective(600px);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(600px);
      }
    }

    @keyframes anim {
      from {
        transform: perspective(100px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      }

      to {
        transform: perspective(600px);
        -webkit-transform: perspective(600px);
      }
    }

    .anim {
        animation-duration : 10s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        backface-visibility: visible !important;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
        animation-name: anim;
        -webkit-animation-name: anim;
    }
```

What's I'm missing in the CSS to solve this issue?

Comment: Could be clipping on the z axis, try pull z position closer to camera

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Simply translate the z-position. There could of course be other additional issues/bugs. This would just be a workaround.